# C++20 - Compile Time Check for Template Function

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, sfinae, c++20

I have a simple template class that:

1. Is instantiated based on another class that receives callbacks.
2. Calls an external function that takes quite a few CPU cycles.
3. Calls into the class that receives the callbacks.

In code:

```
template <class T> 
class Caller {
public:
    T & destination_;
    Caller( T & destination ) : destination_{ destination } {}

    void DoSomethingExpensive() {
        if ( ExpensiveExternalFunction() )
            destination_.ExternalFunctionDone();
    }
};
```

If the `ExternalFunctionDone()` in the destination class doesn't do anything then we will have wasted a lot of compute time in `ExpensiveExternalFunction()`.  Because this is an external function, the compiler can't just optimize all of this away.

Would there be a way in C++20, perhaps using some SFINAE magic, that we could allow the `class T` to simply not implement `ExternalFunctionDone()`?

This seems close ([Templated check for the existence of a class member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/templated-check-for-the-existence-of-a-class-member-function)), but you have to know the name of the type to check it.  In my example, I just know that the type is "T".

Also, I am hoping that there's something nice and clean in C++20 that wraps all of this up in something like:

`if constextpr( std::method_exists( T::ExternalFunctionDone ) )`

Comment: What about the C++20 answer on the question you linked does not satisfy your needs?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/61034367/4323

Comment: Let me clarify the question.  Two things:
1. I am in a template and I don't know the name of my type
2. Is there a cleaner C++20 paradigm.  (std::if_function_defined<>? )

Comment: @JoshK: "*you have to know the name of the type to check it. In my example, I just know that the type is "T".*" So does the answer you linked to. The `has_toString` concept is templated too.

Comment: 1. Your type is called "T."  2. The answer I linked is a good one which is C++20 specific.

Comment: I see what you are saying, I could just pass in "T".   I didn't realize.   

But the first part of my question still stands.  Is there a cleaner way to do this in c++?   "std::is_invocable?"   I couldn't get it to work but it seems close.

Comment: John, thanks, those are good.  I  didn't think of concepts for c++20.   I was hoping there was just some nice little function in the stl...